# protractor angular 5 radio button selection doesn't work consistently

Tags: angular, dom, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to use protractor with angular 5 to select a radio button associated with customer payment methods, however the radio button selection is not stable once its checked and ten times it doesn't.
 code for clicking a radio button in a web checkout:

```
 browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath("//input[@name='paymentMethod' and @type='radio' and @id='874904645420181210']"));
 browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(element(by.xpath("//input[@name='paymentMethod' and @type='radio' and @id='874904645420181210']"))).perform();
 var e = element(by.xpath("//input[@name='paymentMethod' and @type='radio' and @id='874904645420181210']"));
 browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(e), 10000);
 element.all(by.xpath("//input[@name='paymentMethod' and @type='radio'")).then( async function(elm){
 await browser.waitForAngular();
 await browser.sleep(180000);
 await elm[0].click();
 await e.click();
 await browser.waitForAngular();
 await browser.sleep(180000);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `browser.driver.findElement`, it finds the element without waiting for Angular stability. Basically you are calling the selenium-webdriver client directly and your results may vary.

I would avoid using explicit sleeps and calls to waitForAngular. Also think about not using xpath to identify your web elements. This can lead to hard to maintain tests.

```
// Nit: Prefer not to use xpath because these can be brittle.
// Reference http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide
const paymentMethod = element(by.xpath("//input[@name='paymentMethod' and @type='radio' and @id='874904645420181210']"));

// We should wait to see if the element is present before doing anything.
// This should also wait for angular stability with waitForAngular
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(paymentMethod), 10000);
```

Different ways of clicking...

#### With selenium-webdriver actions API

Caution: You could run into issues here since the W3C actions API is in flux with browser driver providers and the selenium-webdriver client.

```
// browser.driver.actions() mouseMove takes a WebElement object.
// So just moving the mouse does not click. You might want to click on it?
// Also assuming that this is the radio button
const paymentMethodWebEl = await paymentMethod.getWebElement();
await browser.driver.actions().mouseMove(paymentMethodWebEl).click().perform();
```

### Protractor's ElementFinder click

Pretty standard clicking.

```
await paymentMethod.click();
```

### Protractor's ElementArrayFinder: getting an index and clicking.

```
// This might be the same step as above to click on a payment radio button
const paymentMethods = element.all(by.xpath("//input[@name='paymentMethod' and @type='radio'"));
// http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.get
await paymentMethods.get(0).click();
```

Comment: can you help me in writing css selector for a single element with different styles(name and class and type).  for input element of type radio                                                                                               <div class="highlight-card ng-tns-c12-5 ng-trigger ng-trigger-fadeInOut ng-star-inserted">
        <div class="custom-checkbox">
          <div class="checkbox" id="payment-methods">
            <input class="ng-tns-c12-5 ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" title="" id="874904645420181210">

Comment: If the id is always constant, I would use the id number here: `element(by.id('874904645420181210'))` or using an ElementFinderArray: `element.all(by.css(.checkbox input[name="paymentMethod"]))`

Comment: thank you. but neither of the solutions are working. and even when I put browser.sleep I don't know why? and the tests are slow as well.

Comment: If you add browser.sleep you are adding your own explicit waits. Adding sleep is not preferred. Maybe use browser.wait(function, timeout) to check for a condition to exist or timeout.

Comment: thank you cnishina. but I still can't click on the input field of type radio. I noticed that there is no form element as a parent for this input; its only a series of div elements

Comment: Are you running this with geckodriver? Is there something happening in your Angular application where Protractor is waiting for stability?